# UnicodeDecodeError with Django Rest Framework on Model's __str__ field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unicode

I'm banging my head on the table regarding this error, and I've scoured the internet but either 1) haven't been able to find the answer or 2) am not knowledgable enough to figure out what's going on.

**The tldr summary of my problem:**

> When I store a non-ASCII character (such as è) in a models.TextField and
>   serialize it with serializers.CharField, I do not encounter and
>   problems. However, if I have a **str** method on the model that
>   returns that same text field, upon serialization I get the following
>   error:
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   5: ordinal not in range(128)

**First of all...**

- I'm running `Python 2.7.10` on OS X.
- I'm using `Django==1.11.7` and `djangorestframework==3.7.3`.
- My `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables are both set to `en_US.UTF-8`.
- Lastly, I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.5.6` and I verified that my database is encoded in `UTF8`.

**The details of my problem:**

I have a simple model as shown below. It has a `name` variable that is a `TextField` as well as a `__str__` method that simply returns `self.name`. I also have defined a `testing` variable that also simply returns `self.name` for demonstration purposes.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(help_text=_('Store Name'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Supplier'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Suppliers'

    def testing(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Next, my serializer is defined as follows.

```
class SupplierSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = ('name', 'testing', '__str__')
```

Finally, I have the following viewset:

```
class SupplierViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Supplier.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SupplierSerializer
```

**The problem:**

When I make a `GET` request to the view, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Observation #1:**

This error only seems to occur when I try to serialize `__str__`. If I remove `__str__` from the serializer (and thus serializer only `name` and `testing`) I don't get any errors. What's odd is that `testing` returns the same exact thing as `__str__` - `self.name`.

**Observation #2:**
I verified that inside the `__str__` method, `self.name` is type `unicode`.
Inside the `testing` method, `self.name` is also type `unicode`.

**Observation #3:**
The full stack trace is given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 105, in render
    allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators
  File "/Users//github///lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py", line 28, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 210, in encode
    return ''.join(chunks)
```

It seems to be an error related to the json encoder?

Does anyone with a deeper understanding of `django` and `unicode` have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Quite apart from anything else, you should consider upgrading to Python 3.

Comment: Why do you put fields for *both* `name` and `__str__` on  your serializer? It doesn't make sense. I think we need to see a bit more of the original context here.   Methods need to use a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Comment: @wim Currently my __str__ method just returns self.name for simplicity sake. The __str__ method actually returns other pieces of data - I'm just not showing it to keep things simple. But regarding your second point - that's a good point... I got into the habit of putting model fields in the Meta.fields tuple, but you bring up a good point that __str__ is technically not a field. But is it a method? I feel like it is a "special" method.

Answer (score 4):

While I do not entirely understand the reason why this fixes the error, setting the `UNICODE_JSON` setting to `False` fixes the error.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'UNICODE_JSON': False,
}
```